# CSS Click effect

Tags: css, animation, focus, pseudo-element

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing:0.5em;
  font-size:2em;
  background:#69797E;
}
.center{
  margin:1% auto;
  width:600px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}

.buton{
  color:#333;
  background:#fff;
  font-size:1.1em;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:1em;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-transition:500ms all ease;
  -moz-transition:500ms all ease;
  -o-transition:500ms all ease ;
  transition:500ms ease;
}

.hover::after,.hover::before,
.text::before,.text::after{
  content:'';
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:absolute;
  background:#FF4343;
  -webkit-transition:500ms all ease-out ;
  -moz-transition:500ms all ease-out ;
  -o-transition:500ms all ease-out ;
  transition: 500ms all ease-out;
}

.hover::after{
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:0;
}

.hover::before{
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  height:0;
}

.text::after{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:0px;
}

.text::before{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:0px;
}

.buton:hover .hover::after{
  width:100%;
  height:3px;
}

.buton:hover .text::after{
  width:100%;
  height:3px;
}

.buton:hover .text::before{
  height:100%;
  width:3px;
}

.buton:hover .hover::before{
  height:100%;
  width:3px;
}

.buton:hover .text,
.buton:hover .fa-home{
  color:#FF4343;
}

.buton:hover .fa-home{
  -webkit-animation-name: spin;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}

/***********************************************/

.hover2::after,.hover2::before,
.text2::before,.text2::after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  background:#9A0089;
}


.hover2::after{
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:0;
  -webkit-transition:350ms all ease-out ;
  -moz-transition:350ms all ease-out ;
  -o-transition:350ms all ease-out ;
  transition: 350ms all ease-out;
}

.text2::before{
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  height:0px;
  -webkit-transition:350ms all ease-out 350ms ;
  -moz-transition:350ms all ease-out 350ms;
  -o-transition:350ms all ease-out 350ms ;
  transition: 350ms all ease-out 350ms;
}

.hover2::before{
  right:0;
  top:0;
  height:0;
  -webkit-transition:350ms all ease-out 1050ms ;
  -moz-transition:350ms all ease-out 1050ms ;
  -o-transition:350ms all ease-out 1050ms ;
  transition: 350ms all ease-out 1050ms;
}

.text2::after{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:0px;
  -webkit-transition:350ms all ease-out 700ms ;
  -moz-transition:350ms all ease-out 700ms ;
  -o-transition:350ms all ease-out 700ms ;
  transition: 350ms all ease-out 700ms;
}



.buton:focus .hover2::after{
  width:100%;
  height:3px;
}

.buton:focus .text2::after{
  width:100%;
  height:3px;
}

.buton:focus .text2::before{
  height:100%;
  width:3px;
}

.buton:focus .hover2::before{
  height:100%;
  width:3px;
}

.buton:focus .text2,
.buton:focus .fa-graduation-cap{
  color:#9A0089;
}

.buton:focus .fa-graduation-cap{
  -webkit-animation-name: up;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 900ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes up {
    from {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }

  10%, 20% {
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
  }

  40%, 60%, 80% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
 
}
```

```html
 <!--FA-->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--FONT-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit:300" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="center">
  
<span class="buton">
  <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
  <span class="hover"></span>
  <span class="text">HOVER EFFECT</span>
</span>
  </br>
 <a href="#" class="buton">
  <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
  <span class="hover2"></span>
  <span class="text2">CLICK EFFECT</span>
</a>

</div>
```

I need help for focus effect. First time the focus animation is successfully working. But two three times it's broken. How can I fix that.

and I've one more question for you guys. Looks like my css code is very complex. I will use a framework but I can not decide which one to choose. Less or Sass why?

Answer (score 0):

for a easy way to do what you want, you can just remove all effect while you blur the second button, make sure all animation running right next time.

```css
body {
        font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 0.5em;
        font-size: 2em;
        background: #69797E;
    }
    
    .center {
        margin: 1% auto;
        width: 600px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .buton {
        color: #333;
        background: #fff;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 1em;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: 500ms all ease;
        -moz-transition: 500ms all ease;
        -o-transition: 500ms all ease;
        transition: 500ms ease;
    }
    
    .hover::after,
    .hover::before,
    .text::before,
    .text::after {
        content: '';
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: absolute;
        background: #FF4343;
        -webkit-transition: 500ms all ease-out;
        -moz-transition: 500ms all ease-out;
        -o-transition: 500ms all ease-out;
        transition: 500ms all ease-out;
    }
    
    .hover::after {
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
    
    .hover::before {
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
    
    .text::after {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 0px;
    }
    
    .text::before {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 0px;
    }
    
    .buton:hover .hover::after {
        width: 100%;
        height: 3px;
    }
    
    .buton:hover .text::after {
        width: 100%;
        height: 3px;
    }
    
    .buton:hover .text::before {
        height: 100%;
        width: 3px;
    }
    
    .buton:hover .hover::before {
        height: 100%;
        width: 3px;
    }
    
    .buton:hover .text,
    .buton:hover .fa-home {
        color: #FF4343;
    }
    
    .buton:hover .fa-home {
        -webkit-animation-name: spin;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }
    /***********************************************/
    
    .hover2::after,
    .hover2::before,
    .text2::before,
    .text2::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        background: #9A0089;
    }
    
    .hover2::after {
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 350ms all ease-out;
        -moz-transition: 350ms all ease-out;
        -o-transition: 350ms all ease-out;
        transition: 350ms all ease-out;
    }
    
    .text2::before {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 350ms all ease-out 350ms;
        -moz-transition: 350ms all ease-out 350ms;
        -o-transition: 350ms all ease-out 350ms;
        transition: 350ms all ease-out 350ms;
    }
    
    .hover2::before {
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 350ms all ease-out 1050ms;
        -moz-transition: 350ms all ease-out 1050ms;
        -o-transition: 350ms all ease-out 1050ms;
        transition: 350ms all ease-out 1050ms;
    }
    
    .text2::after {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 350ms all ease-out 700ms;
        -moz-transition: 350ms all ease-out 700ms;
        -o-transition: 350ms all ease-out 700ms;
        transition: 350ms all ease-out 700ms;
    }
    
    .buton:focus .hover2::after {
        width: 100%;
        height: 3px;
    }
    
    .buton:focus .text2::after {
        width: 100%;
        height: 3px;
    }
    
    .buton:focus .text2::before {
        height: 100%;
        width: 3px;
    }
    
    .buton:focus .hover2::before {
        height: 100%;
        width: 3px;
    }

    .buton:not(:focus) .hover2::after,
    .buton:not(:focus) .text2::after,
    .buton:not(:focus) .text2::before,
    .buton:not(:focus) .hover2::before
    {
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     -webkit-transition: none;
        -moz-transition: none;
        -o-transition: none;
        transition: none;
    }
    
    .buton:focus .text2,
    .buton:focus .fa-graduation-cap {
        color: #9A0089;
    }
    
    .buton:focus .fa-graduation-cap {
        -webkit-animation-name: up;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 900ms;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes up {
        from {
            transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        }
        10%,
        20% {
            transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
        }
        30%,
        50%,
        70%,
        90% {
            transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
        }
        40%,
        60%,
        80% {
            transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
        }
        to {
            transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        }
    }
```

```html
<!--FA-->
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <!--FONT-->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit:300" rel="stylesheet">


 <div class="center">
   
 <span class="buton">
   <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
   <span class="hover"></span>
   <span class="text">HOVER EFFECT</span>
 </span>
   </br>
  <a href="#" class="buton">
   <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
   <span class="hover2"></span>
   <span class="text2">CLICK EFFECT</span>
 </a>

 </div>
```

Is this you want??

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank u so much mate.